# Saddle point and stationary point approximation of the Airy equation

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

Happy New Year to you all.

Let $$\tag 1 J(N)=\int_a^b e^{Nf(x)}dx$$ where $N\in\mathbb R$ and $N>>1$ and $f(x)$ has a global maximum at $x=x_0$ with  Taylor expansion $$f(x) \approx f(x_0)-|f''(x_0)|\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}.$$ Then by the *saddle point approximation*, we get 
$$ \tag 2 J(N)\approx \frac{e^{Nf(x_0)}}{\sqrt{N}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{|f''(x_0)|}}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\right).$$

Let $$\tag 3  Ai(x)= \int_\gamma \exp{\left(tx-\frac{t^3}{3}\right)}dt$$ where $\gamma$ is a contour in $\mathbb{C}$ chosen such that the integral converges and the integrand vanishes as $t\to\infty$.

First question: For $x>0$, I want to find an approximation to (3). So, by letting $t=u \sqrt{x}$ , I get $$ Ai(x) = \sqrt{x} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\exp{\left(\left(u -\frac{u^3}{3}\right)x^{3/2}\right)}$$ Doing so allows me to identify the following:$$ N= x^{3/2}~~~f(u)=u-u^3/3~~~$$ from which I get $$ Ai(x>0) = \sqrt{2\pi}e^{{2/3}z^{3/2}}x^{-1/4}\left(1+O\left(z^{-3/2}\right)\right).$$ However, the solution is given as $$ Ai(x>0) = \sqrt{2\pi}e^{{-2/3}z^{3/2}}x^{-1/4}\left(1+\left(x^{-3/2}\right)\right).$$ Obviously, the my trouble stems from the fact that using  (2), I keep getting 2/3 and not -2/3. I'd be very happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Second question: For $x<0$, can I get help in using the *stationary phase approximation* to approximate (2)?

Please, if what I've done above is complete hokum, let me know as well. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be $N=x^{3/2}$ and in the integral before this formula as well (and $x^{3/2}$ should be part of the exponent, too).

Comment: You found the asymptotic expansion of the Bi-function. The Ai-function is dominated by the saddle point at $u_0=-1$. The Ai-function should be defined such that it vanishes for $x\to \infty $ (I guess there is another typo in the post) which your solution does not do.

Comment: @Fabian: I've fixed the  typo.

Comment: @Fabian: Can you please point out the typo. did I define The Ai-function incorrectly?

Comment: I guess Ai is defined such that it vanishes for $x\to\infty$ (and not fur $t\to\infty$ as you state in your post).

Answer (score 2):

I) Judging from OP's eq. (2), it seems OP is conflating [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method) in real analysis, and the [method of steepest descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) in complex analysis. The latter has extra complex phase factors, which undoubtedly resolves OP's sign problem.

II) In more detail, the [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) of first kind is defined as

$$ Ai(z)~:=~\int_{i\mathbb{R}+0^{+}} \! \frac{du}{2\pi i} \exp\left(\frac{u^3}{3}-uz \right)~\stackrel{u=\sqrt{r} t}{=}~\frac{\sqrt{r}}{2\pi i} \int_{i\mathbb{R}+0^{+}} \! dt~\exp\left(r^{\frac{3}{2}} S(t,\theta) \right) , \qquad z~=~re^{i\theta},$$ 
$$ S(t,\theta)~:=~\frac{t^3}{3}-te^{i\theta}, \qquad S^{\prime}(t,\theta)~:=~t^2-e^{i\theta},\qquad S^{\prime\prime}(t,\theta)~:=~2t. \tag{1}$$

Here $r\gg 1$. There are two critical points:

$$ t_{\sigma} ~=~\sigma e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}, \qquad S_{\sigma}~=~ - \frac{2\sigma}{3}e^{\frac{3i\theta}{2}} , \qquad S^{\prime\prime}_{\sigma}~=~  2\sigma e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}, \qquad \sigma ~\in~\{\pm 1\} .\tag{2}$$

The steepest decent contribution from each critical point comes from a [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral):

$$ I_{\sigma}~=~\frac{\sqrt{r}}{2\pi i}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{-r^{\frac{3}{2}} S^{\prime\prime}_{\sigma}} } \exp\left(r^{\frac{3}{2}} S_{\sigma} \right)$$
$$ ~=~\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}i \sqrt[4]{r}}  \exp\left(-\frac{2\sigma}{3}r^{\frac{3}{2}} e^{\frac{3i\theta}{2}} -\frac{i\theta}{4}\right)\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}  \pm i & \text{for}& \sigma~=~+1 \cr\cr 1 & \text{for}& \sigma~=~-1\end{array}  \right\} .\tag{3}$$

*Case $z<0 ~\Leftrightarrow ~\theta=\pi$:* Critical points: $t_{\sigma}=\sigma i$. The $Ai$-contour along the imaginary axis is reproduced by a combination of both the two steepest decent contours:

$$ Ai(-r)~\sim~\pm I_{+1}-I_{-1}~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt[4]{r}}\sin\left( \frac{2}{3}r^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
$$~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt[4]{r}}\cos\left( \frac{2}{3}r^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\quad \text{for} \quad r\to \infty.  \tag{4}$$

*Case $z>0 ~\Leftrightarrow~ \theta=0$:* Critical points: $t_{\sigma}=\sigma$. The $Ai$-contour  along the imaginary axis is reproduced by the steepest decent contour corresponding to the critical point $t_{+1}$:

$$ Ai(r)~\sim~\pm I_{+1}~=~\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt[4]{r}}\exp\left(- \frac{2}{3}r^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\quad \text{for} \quad r\to \infty. \tag{5}$$

The $\pm$ in eqs. (3), (4) & (5) are correlated. See also the Wikipedia page for the [Stokes phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon).